# latest Xemacs for Windows binary download

Tags: windows, binary, installation, xemacs

I'm trying to get an updated version for Windows vista. I previously got 21.4.22 but it's been a year since that release. The linux versions should be 22.x. I'm wondering if anyone else builds stable binaries for Windows ?

21.4.22 has several bugs and I cannot figure out how to fix them. I know Xemacs is not as active as GNU emacs but still aren't there any Xemacs users on windows who build their own copies even if the official site doesn't ?

I would like to be able to compare buffers, files and directories apart from being able to edit any file : java, javascript, ruby, .bat, .sh, .xml, etc.

It will also be nice if I can interface with sqlplus(oracle) and other commandline sql tools like with a previous edition I had.

Comment: I can't believe that nobody bothered answering this question. I don't want to add a bounty to this -- I guess that I will need to switch to GNU emacs to stay current. I guess that I will need to improve my emacsfu to get more fluent with it.

anyone knows how to close this question ? When I tried to close it, it questioned me why ? none of  the featured answers to that question was relevant (which is , NOBODY BOTHERED TO ANSWER THE QUESTION).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess XEmacs is dying (especially on windows) -- I came here because Martin fowler talked about it long ago.

Now that nobody has bothered to answer this question, I'm thinking that the community is dying and I switch to a better platform(GNU emacs) -- sure there'd be some features I might miss (don't know which).